# Dell Inspiron 7559 GPU issues

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, dell

I have started installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Inspiron 7559, but failed to boot. After research, I have found https://connorkuehl.github.io/dell-inspiron-7559-linux-guide/index.html where is described how to install Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04. Everything went well and now I'm running ubuntu, but only on Intel HD Graphics.
Is there a possibility to use Nvidia GPU?

When I'm trying to switch to Nvidia `sudo prime-select nvidia`, I cannot boot anymore. Boot stalls at "Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes" with an "Timeout" error.

My hardware:

```
$ sudo lshw -c Display 

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"              
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

My Grub defaults:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi="
```

## Update:

Purged all NVidia drivers. Installed version 390. Ubuntu was running, but very laggy. Started to look at what `Joshua Besneatte` posted, but I'm unable to install version

```
Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-340
```

but version is present on https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic

## Update 2

I decided to install XFCE Desktop and use HD Graphics only. Works like a charm. Performance is much better. I'll stick to XFCE, but would like also to find a solution to run with Nvidia.

Comment: Have you tried enabling proprietary drivers in settings?
If it isn't available, make sure you are connected to the internet or plugin the USB drive you used to install Ubuntu and the sources should pick it up.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte That's not the right duplicate question.